# no line endings when running awk in batch file

Tags: batch-file, awk, newline

An `awk` command is run from a command shell under Windows, and gives this output

```
a a a
b b b
c c c
```

When I save that command in a batch file, and run it, I get

```
a a a b b b c c c
```

---

`awk` has been installed from GnuWin32, and I'm using version GNU Awk 3.1.6
The `awk` command in question is `awk "ORS=NR%3?FS:RS" input_file`

---

The input file is

```
a
a
a
b
b
b
c
c
c
```

---

**How can I get my line endings back?**

---

Results after some experimenting:

- `awk "1" input_file`
  Gives CR+LF line endings, adds an additional line ending at the end of the file (which input_file lacks)
- `awk -v ORS=. "1" input_file`
  Gives this as output: `a.a.a.b.b.b.c.c.c.` (no line ending)
- The first batch of proposals of *Ed Morton - see below -* (using `\r` and `\n` without single quotes `'`) all yield the same output, regardless of the setting of `RS` and `ORS`: all output is given with CR+LF line endings
- I got different results when `-v BINMODE=3` was added:
  All output is still given with CR+LF line endings, but for some commands, double line endings are printed out `0x0D 0x0A 0x0D 0x0A`. The table below lists which combinations yield two line endings per input line, blanks yield single line endings:

  ```
         ORS : \n | \r | \r\n
  -----------+----+----+-------
          \n |    | XX |  XX
    RS:   \r | XX |    |  XX
        \r\n |    |    |
  ```
- btw, the reason why I removed the single quotes from the `RS` and `ORS` values: all output then has one or two single quotes added at the end - and only at the end: a single when `ORS='\r'`, two with a line ending in between for the other values. Using double quotes gives the same result as using no quotes.

Comment: Don't know why you get different results in a script than on the shell, but it could probably be fixed you run your command with `awk -v RS='\r\n' ...`

Comment: @user000001 No, it doesn't, unfortunately. Using this, all output is still on one line, both when run directly or via a batch file.

Comment: I don't understand what you're telling us above about what was happening with quotes but I believe Windows has some bizarre quoting rules so maybe try moving all of the variable assignments inside the BEGIN section, e.g. using `BEGIN{RS=...}` instead of `-v RS=...`. If that doesn't work, move the awk script into a file and invoke with `awk -f` to see if that does it. Otherwise, I'm out of ideas other than that you get cygwin and run from that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If GnuWin32 contains `paste`, the simpler choice would be: `paste - - - < filename`

Comment: Well, that's yet another nice usage of paste I didn't think of. Thank you! It works very well and my original intent is accomplished. Leaves me still wondering why there is a discrepancy between using awk directly or via a batch file.

Comment: I'm guessing that awk uses `\n` line endings by default, and DOS expects `\r\n`

Answer (score 1):

Parenthesize your ternary expression as this:

```
awk "ORS=NR%3?FS:RS"
```

is ambiguous and would produce a syntax error on some awks so change it to:

```
awk "ORS=(NR%3?FS:RS)"
```

That probably won't solve your problem though.

Now try `awk -v RS='\n' -v ORS='\r\n' ...` and change your script to just `1` to see if the line endings are reproduced. It's GOT to be something to do with line endings so some combination of `\r` and `\n` for RS and ORS must do it.

Also, try setting `-v BINMODE=3` - not sure if it affects your environment but on cygwin that's necessary for gawk to even see the `\r`s.

So, try these to see which reproduces the line endings as-is:

```
awk -v RS='\n' -v ORS='\n' "1" input_file
awk -v RS='\r' -v ORS='\n' "1" input_file
awk -v RS='\r\n' -v ORS='\n' "1" input_file

awk -v RS='\n' -v ORS='\r' "1" input_file
awk -v RS='\r' -v ORS='\r' "1" input_file
awk -v RS='\r\n' -v ORS='\r' "1" input_file

awk -v RS='\n' -v ORS='\r\n' "1" input_file
awk -v RS='\r' -v ORS='\r\n' "1" input_file
awk -v RS='\r\n' -v ORS='\r\n' "1" input_file
```

and if none of them do then try adding `-v BINMODE=3` to each, e.g.:

```
awk -v BINMODE=3 -v RS='\n' -v ORS='\n' "1" input_file
awk -v BINMODE=3 -v RS='\r' -v ORS='\n' "1" input_file
awk -v BINMODE=3 -v RS='\r\n' -v ORS='\n' "1" input_file

awk -v BINMODE=3 -v RS='\n' -v ORS='\r' "1" input_file
awk -v BINMODE=3 -v RS='\r' -v ORS='\r' "1" input_file
awk -v BINMODE=3 -v RS='\r\n' -v ORS='\r' "1" input_file

awk -v BINMODE=3 -v RS='\n' -v ORS='\r\n' "1" input_file
awk -v BINMODE=3 -v RS='\r' -v ORS='\r\n' "1" input_file
awk -v BINMODE=3 -v RS='\r\n' -v ORS='\r\n' "1" input_file
```

Then update whichever one works to replace `"1"` with `"ORS=(NR%3?FS:RS)"`.

Comment: Thank you. I updated my question with some results. The more I try, the less I understand, I must say...